# search in multidimensional array if value is true or false

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a multidimensional array looks like as below

```
{
  patient: {
    value: 66,
    entry_date: "2017-01-17",
    source: "self entered",
    risk_level: nil,
    risk_ranges: [{
      level: "low",
      is_active: false,
      range_low: 80,
      range_high: 139,
      unit: "mg/dL"
    }, {
      level: "moderate",
      is_active: false,
      range_low: 140,
      range_high: 199,
      unit: "mg/dL"
    }, {
      level: "high",
      is_active: false,
      range_low: 200,
      range_high: nil,
      unit: "mg/dL"
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to find out if `is_active` is `false` in the `risk_ranges` array.

Of course I can access to `patient.risk_ranges[0].is_active`, `patient.risk_ranges[1].is_active` and `patient.risk_ranges[2].is_active` but wondering if there's a better way to write this.

if the `is_active` is `false` in all 3 objects in array then set `patient.risk_level = high`

How can I do that?

Comment: This is not an array, is this the format your data is in?

Comment: yes thats the format of the data

Comment: Is this some form of a `Struct`? You say of course I can do `patient.risk_ranges` but given the `Hash` structure you have you cannot do this. it would be more like `patient[:risk_ranges]` because that is how `Hash` access works.

Comment: Apparently it's something else entirely, likely AR objects

Comment: @MarkThomas ugghhh in that case the solution is much simpler and can be handled purely in SQL without the need to iterate at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of

```
if patient.risk_ranges.all?{ |range| range.is_active == false} 
   patient.risk_level = "high"
end
```

Comment: You can simplify it as `{|range| !range[:is_active]}` working with it as a hash.

Comment: `patient.risk_ranges.none?(&:is_active)` would look much nicer :)

Comment: ahh thank you so much sara. I was trying similar thing but was missing .all